# React memory leaks warning with using a stateful button in a dialog or alert in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state, react-hooks, jss

I am using Material UI for a component library and noticed when I click a button within a Dialog or Alert (both components manage states of open/closed), I get a memory leaks warning. I am unsure of how to fix the problem here. The button component uses state to create an active class when clicked, which uses a `setTimeout` onClick to make the button click more visible/longer lasting in the UI.

This is the button component:

```
function Button({
  classes,
  className,
  onClick,
  ...props
}) {
  let [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  let handleClick = e => {
    e.persist();
    setActive(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setActive(false);
    }, 250);
  if (typeof onClick === "function") onClick(e);
  };

  return (
    <MuiButton
      variant={finalVariant(variant)}
      className={`${active ? "Mui-active" : ""} ${className}`}
      classes={buttonClasses}
      onClick={handleClick}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

let containedStyle = color => ({
  "&:active": {
    backgroundColor: color.dark
  },
  "&.Mui-active": {
    backgroundColor: color.dark
  }
});
```

This is the memory leaks warning I get when I click a button inside either an Alert or Dialog component:

```
index.js:1437 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

I've tried using `useEffect` as suggested by the warning to clear the active state but haven't had luck. Here is a demo of what happens when I use a custom button built with MUI that uses hooks to manage state when the button is used in a dialog or alert https://codesandbox.io/s/traffic-light-using-hooks-zpfrc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: stackblitz.com/fork/react can you add your code here, so I can have a clear view

Comment: Here is a demo of the warning https://codesandbox.io/s/traffic-light-using-hooks-zpfrc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: done anaswered ;)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `handleClick` function uses `setTimeout`:

```
  let handleClick = e => {
    e.persist();
    setActive(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setActive(false);
    }, 250);
    if (typeof onClick === "function") onClick(e);
  };
```

To update the state.

The component is getting unmounted by the parent component when `onClick` is called, but there is still a subscription (your timeout) kept alive.

This isn't really a big deal if it's a one-off event, like in this case. It's a warning, not an error. The main purpose of this warning is to let you know if you are keeping subscriptions or references around for a long time after something is unmounted.

There are a few work-arounds to get rid of the warning by setting a flag if the component is unmounted and, if the flag is set, not updating state, but that doesn't really solve the problem that there is a reference to a component kept around after it's unmounted.

A better way of resolving this problem would be to keep a reference to the timeout using `React.useRef()` and then clearing it in `useEffect()`, like this:

```
function Button({
  classes,
  className,
  onClick,
  ...props
}) {
  let [active, setActive] = useState(false);
+ const timeout = React.useRef(undefined);

+ React.useEffect(() => {
+   return () => {
+     if (timeout.current !== undefined) {
+       clearTimeout(timeout.current);
+     }
+   }
+ }, []);

  let handleClick = e => {
    e.persist();
    setActive(true);
-   setTimeout(() => {
+   timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setActive(false);
    }, 250);
    if (typeof onClick === "function") onClick(e);
  }; 

  return (
    <MuiButton
      variant={finalVariant(variant)}
      className={`${active ? "Mui-active" : ""} ${className}`}
      classes={buttonClasses}
      onClick={handleClick}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

This could be encapsulated in a hook like so:

```
  function useSafeTimeout() {
    const timeouts = React.useRef([])
    React.useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        timeouts.forEach(timeout => {
          clearTimeout(timeout)
        })
      }
    }, [])

    return React.useCallback((fn, ms, ...args) => {
      const cancel = setTimeout(fn, ms, ...args)
      timeouts.current.push(cancel)
    }, [])
  }
```

And used in this manner:

```
function Button({
  classes,
  className,
  onClick,
  ...props
}) {
  let [active, setActive] = useState(false);
+ const setTimeout = useSafeTimeout();

  let handleClick = e => {
    e.persist();
    setActive(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setActive(false);
    }, 250);
    if (typeof onClick === "function") onClick(e);
  }; 

  return (
    <MuiButton
      variant={finalVariant(variant)}
      className={`${active ? "Mui-active" : ""} ${className}`}
      classes={buttonClasses}
      onClick={handleClick}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey Dan! Thank you for your answer :) the code snippet above added to the code demo does clear the memory leaks warning (whoo!) but it looks like it doesn't clear the active state/class after the timeout as desired. I've updated here: https://codesandbox.io/s/traffic-light-using-hooks-zpfrc **ive made the active class set a red background color to the buttons to make it clear as to what's happening throughout the flow of clicking a button -> seeing the state change. Apologies if im missing something obvious!!

Comment: Here is the version without using the useEffect + useRef for comparison: https://codesandbox.io/s/traffic-light-using-hooks-i8bid

Comment: Oh, my bad, I made a mistake. Fixed it! the timeout was being removed every time the component re-rendered rather than only when the component was unmounted.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me/modifying! :D ! I also tried adding the change and am getting a maximum call stack size exceeded: ` var cancel = setTimeout.apply(undefined, [fn, ms].concat(args));` . Thats with implementing the `useSafeTimeout` function and setting this `const setTimeout` with that function to be called in the handleClick.. any ideas? Im going to keep poking around but this is the current state with the revisions here https://codesandbox.io/s/traffic-light-using-hooks-i8bid

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for the problem:

```
function Button({
  classes,
  className,
  onClick,
  ...props
}) {
  let [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  let timeoutIds = useRef([]);

    let registerTimeout = (f, ms) => {
    let timeoutId = setTimeout(f, ms);
    timeoutIds.current.push(timeoutId);
  };

  let handleClick = e => {
    e.persist();
    setActive(true);
    if (typeof onClick === "function") onClick(e);
  };

  let cleanup = () => {
    timeoutIds.current.forEach(clearTimeout);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active === true) {
      registerTimeout(() => setActive(false), 250);
    }
    return cleanup;
  }, [active]);

  return (
    <MuiButton
      variant={finalVariant(variant)}
      className={`${active ? "Mui-active" : ""} ${className}`}
      classes={buttonClasses}
      onClick={handleClick}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```